# Cosmos Java SDK throwing exceptions with x-ms-substatus=10003

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are performing a load test using globalclientthroughputcontrol feature to apply client side throttle for write operations and during the test, CosmosDiagnostics logs reports 429 status code and 10003 substatus code.I am not able to find any documents related to substatus code 10003.Please share your experience if you have encountered this issue before.

As per microsoft troubleshooting guide I found the below information.
// 429: Request Rate Too Large
RUBudgetExceeded = 3200,            // RUs allocated has been consumed.
GatewayThrottled = 3201,            // Gateway throttled volume of requests.
StoredProcedureConcurrency = 3084   // Concurrency limit in stored procedure reached.

Comment: When you get a 429, you’ve exceeded RU for a 1-second boundary. One of the returned headers will tell you how long you have to sleep until your RU-debt is paid off.

Comment: I think StatusCode 429 and SubStatusCode 3200 are for RUBudgetExceeded and cosmos will start throttling (429s) and also send us a response header with x-ms-retry-after-ms to retry the operation. In my scenario, I am getting a response as StatusCode 429 and SubStatusCode 10003.

Answer (score 0):

10003 is related to your Global or Local Throughput Control.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/quickstart-java#use-throughput-control

Your application must be setting some throughput limit and the SDK is enforcing this